# Word for a person who condescends himself to praise others

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sure there are some obvious words that mean this but I can't think of any. For example, he might say, "You've done an amazing job! Much better than what I could've done."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the person is displaying modesty. Depending on how much the person condescends their position in saying "than what I could've done", I might say s/he is being

> [over(ly)-modest](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/over-modest?__utma=1.1286849461.1363270970.1365058710.1365068405.8&__utmb=1.1.10.1365068405&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1365068405.8.3.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=125236234)

Comment: The link shows "over-modest" only. *"Overly-modest" is incorrectly punctuated: it should be "overly modest", so the conflation of the two phrases using those parentheses is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean "someone who [deprecates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deprecation) himself". You might call that person a *[self-deprecator](http://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-5067/Are-You-a-SelfDeprecator.html)*. The word isn't in the dictionary, but it's been used, and it's not off the wall.

Comment: I think the more common usage is as an adjective, 'self-deprecating'.

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, I agree: "a self-deprecating person", but the OP asked for "a word" (a one-word name [noun] is what I assumed was wanted).

Comment: Sometimes what a person asks for is not the same as the best thing that answers their need. In particular, single word requests are almost always presumptuous in their expectation of a single word.

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, I agree. But in this case, there **is** a single word that fills the bill. And **sometimes** giving the OP what **I** think may best fit their needs is also presumptuous, especially when I don't know how the OP plans to use the answer. However, I'm clearly not at all shy about telling anyone what I think they should say instead of what they want to say. I think that's quite evident to anyone here who regularly reads my answers & comments. I'm neither shy nor overly modest nor self-deprecatory. I **usually** say what I mean & mean what I say, even when trying to be diplomatic.